# How to handle file auto download in internet explorer/chrome using robot framework?

Tags: download, robotframework

I am trying to download few files with file type as *tsv, csv, txt, xls and xlsx* using Robot framework through IE/chrome but each time ,it is asking either to open, save or cancel file after clicking on download button. I want it to get auto-downloaded to specific location without asking user to perform open/save or cancel.Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you provide us with a [mcve] so that we know what you've tried so far?

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by opening chrome using existing chrome profile instead of launching new chrome.